# How to override BTDF Settings file name?

Tags: azure-devops, biztalk, azure-pipelines, biztalk-2010, btdf

I am creating the release pipeline for the BizTalk solution (2010) in Azure DevOps.

In BTDF - the environment specific settings file generated, will be of the format `Exported_DevSettings`, `Exported_TestSettings`.

But the BTDF - deploy in azure expects the settings file name of the following format: `{0}_settings.xml`

If the file name in the settings file is changed BTDF build fails with the following error in XmlPreprocess.exe:

> /s:: Argument expects a parameter

Is there any setting in the `.btdfproj` file that allows to override the local settings name?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include what might cause that error.  Does that solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Edit the **Settings File Name:** settings in SettingsFileGenerator.xml

And change

```
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Settings File Name:</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s40"><Data ss:Type="String">Exported_LocalSettings.xml</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s40"><Data ss:Type="String">DevSettings.xml</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s40"><Data ss:Type="String">Exported_TestSettings.xml</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s40"><Data ss:Type="String">Exported_ProdSettings.xml</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

To

```
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Settings File Name:</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s40"><Data ss:Type="String">Local_settings.xml</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s40"><Data ss:Type="String">Dev_settings.xml</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s40"><Data ss:Type="String">Test_settings.xml</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s40"><Data ss:Type="String">Prod_settings.xml</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

Also as per the TechNet thread [Not ble to deploy application through BTDF framework in Visual Studio 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c53fe413-8310-4b78-9f59-72f966bb113a/not-ble-to-deploy-application-through-btdf-framework-in-visual-studio-2013?forum=biztalkgeneral) make sure that the `SkipExportSettings` is set to `False` in the Properties in the MSBuild section

```
<MSBuild
      Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
      Properties="LoadedPropsFromEnvSettings=True;SkipExportSettings=True;$(PropsFromEnvSettingsDelimited)"
      Targets="$(TargetsAfterLoadPropsFromEnvSettings)"
      UseResultsCache="false" UnloadProjectsOnCompletion="true" />
```

Comment: I have tried that when the file name's in the settings file is changed BTDF build fails with the following error in XmlPreprocess.exe:

/s:: Argument expects a parameter

Comment: @SNG See this thread. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c53fe413-8310-4b78-9f59-72f966bb113a/not-ble-to-deploy-application-through-btdf-framework-in-visual-studio-2013?forum=biztalkgeneral  Check that SkipExportSettings=False